# Honeypot CAPTCHA For Transactional Webpage

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, captcha, honeypot

I'm aiming to implement a HoneyPot Captcha in .NET for a page which has a list of inventory, and each item of inventory has its own buy button along with a text field that lets the user enter the quantity desired.

```
Item 1     Qty Text Field     (Buy)
Item 2     Qty Text Field     (Buy)
Item 3     Qty Text Field     (Buy)
etc...
```

Each Buy button, when clicked and successfully taken to the next page, will temporarily lock the selected quantity of inventory.

Do I need to have a separate honeypot CAPTCHA field for each Buy Button, essentially making as many forms and honeypot captchas as there are buy buttons?

Or will a single honeypot CAPTCHA field named appropriately to lure a bot, but generic to the page and not repeated or specific to any given Quantity Field/Buy Button combination, do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need one honeypot per form.
In your case, you just have to check whether you have multiple forms. It depends a bit on what you are trying to do and how you are doing it, but in your case one form per line should work.

In that case, you'd need one honeypot per form.

On the other hand, if you only have one form, you obviously only need one honeypot.